# Interaction between two classes

Tags: class

I want to know the best way to "share" or have access to attributes between 2 classes like this :

```
class A {
    public A() {
        B myClassB = new B();
    }

    int attributeA;
}

Class B {
    int foo() {
         // I want to have something like : return attributeA;   
    }
}
```

I hope that it's clear. If someone has a better way to ask the question let me know 'cause I really don't know how.

Thanks.

Comment: I have understood your question, you can share the attributes as shown below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say by **encapsulation** you could share the fields (attributes) between classes. It is a fundamental OOP concept which helps a programmer to modify the already implemented code without breaking the code of others who use the fields.

Consider the below example (Java)

```
public class Person{

   public  String name = "John";
   public int age = 25;
}
```

Sharing Person class's attributes with another class

```
public class EncapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.name = "Tom";
        p.age = 20;
        System.out.println(p.name);
        System.out.println(p.age);
    }
}
```

The above approach is bad way to share(access) attributes between classes because any one can change the fields because they are public. So when you change them, they get changed for everyone (even for those who didn't want). It is like you're breaking the code of others.

See the below example which uses encapsulation

```
 public class Person{

       private  String name;
       private int age;

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setAge(int age) {
           this.age = age;
       }

       public int getName() {
           return age;
       }
    }
```

Sharing Person class's attributes with another class

```
public class EncapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setName("Tom");
        p.setAge(20)
        System.out.println(p.getName());
        System.out.println(p.getAge());
    }
}
```

By making the attributes private and accessing them using the getters and setters methods, you are hiding the attributes with in the class. So whenever you set the attributes in another class, you're not breaking other programmers' code.